# Links to another service with HATEOAS

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm building microservices using Spring Cloud Netflix, Spring Data JPA, and Spring Data REST.

The responses of my services are REST-HATEOAS formatted. Is there a way to automatically add links to other microservices in my responses?

For example, saying I have 2 microservices: Team and Player. When requesting a team, is there an (easy) way to add links to players (i.e. to the Player service) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, considering that you're completely in a spring realm you can use [spring-hateoas](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/)

Its centered around Spring MVC Controllers, and I guess that you have a controller as a front of your *Player* service.

You'll find [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial) a short intro guide with an analogues *customer* - *orders* example. The main thing is that you're able to automate link building without any hard coding, which really simplifies the maintenance

Comment: Actually I'm using RestRepositories, so most of the time I don't implement controllers (but they can be added). Anyway, this solution works but I wondered if it can be done in a more automated way (maybe with a Feign/Spring-data-rest integration )